# Can you create Android RemoteViews Widgets in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, remoteview, glance-appwidget

I have an Android app that uses the Glance API to create remote views. i.e. the widgets you can place on the Android homescreen.

Does Flutter also have the ability to create RemoteViews in Android?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26134